# No search results with filebrowser and terminal

Tags: gnome, nautilus, find, dconf, gvfs

Hei,
Ubuntu 22.10

I don't get search results while searching for files both with databrowser
and terminal.
Concrete: "Search" stopps after search in the first mentioned directory.

A lot of "permission denied in the terminal.
F.e.:
find: ‘/home/jac/.cache/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/jac/.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/jac/.gvfs’: Permission denied

Thanks for help.

Comment: please add ls -la for the cache directory and some of the file/dirs it does this. .cache should be owned by "jac" so if you use jac to search that notice should not show.   Regarding terminal do `sudo updatedb` and then use `locate {whatyouwanttosearch}` It is a lot quicker and does not error out on permissions

Comment: @Rinzwind
 Thank You!
1.I can find files now with locate but not with GUI file browser. It doesnt work.
2.After sudo updatedb I got this result:
jac@jac-Aspire-F5-573:~$ sudo updatedb
[sudo] password for jac: 
/usr/bin/find: '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied